# Updating one sheet that updates another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I update to track trends. I have another sheet for the most current data from the first. How do I get the second sheet to update automatically when I enter a new set of data on the first?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You will need to add a lot more details about your setup. As it is, it will be nearly impossible to answer your question. Please read this: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are several ways. Have cells references that refer to the other sheet. Or Formulas. Or, with the latest Excel365, Dynamic Formulas. (Or macros, or VBA). Simplest: add the sheet name (in single quotes if if has spaces in it) in front of the cell reference. Example ='Sheet 1'!A1. Google Relative and Absolute Cell References for more control.

Comment: If you can provide a sample, it will be more helpful.